# SVN: How to get original date file was uploaded if file has been moved?

Tags: windows, svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I am working with Windows 7 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.5.

I uploaded a file **A.sql** to SVN to a folder **FolderA**. Then the file was moved to another folder **FolderB** by someone else.

Now I am trying to find out when I uploaded that file to folder **FolderA**.

In TortoiseSVN I tried `Show log` option for this file, but in the `Log Messages`window it is showing first history item as the date when the file was moved to folder **FolderB**.
 
Similarly I tried `Revision graph` option for this file, but got the same result.

How can I find out when this file was originally uploaded to SVN?

Thanks

Comment: You could try to uncheck the box "Stop on Copy/ Rename" (or similiar) in the lower left corner